# Adding jogl in java.library.path

Tags: jogl

I am implementing the globe project on windows-7 platform in eclipse neon.
But when i run the project it given an error like:

---

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   no jogl in java.library.path

---

I have followed each and every link to solve the following error but it still is arising. 
Does anyone know a confirmed solution that is sure gonna work in this case?
Early response will be appreciated.
Thank You guyzz in advance.

Comment: You haven't: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE#Eclipse_IDE_project  I have used JOGL since 2006 and it works. I'm currently using Eclipse Oxygen, it works in older versions too. Of course, don't mix incompatible versions of JOGL and Gluegen together ;)

Comment: Thanks gouessej for your comment. Do i need to follow the same steps for the existing project as I do not want to create anew project??

Comment: Yes, except the very first one consisting in creating a new project obviously. You can modify the settings of an existing project.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)  gouessej

Comment: You're welcome. Most JogAmp users are on our official forum: http://forum.jogamp.org If you have any questions, I encourage you to post it into this forum. Only a few of them come on StackOverflow.